# Spring security OAuth2 not protecting websocket endpoints when using SockJS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am implementing websockets in spring boot and I want to protect my websocket endpoints with OAuth2, but there is a problem when connecting with SockJS. It seems to completely ignore all the OAuth2 security I've setup.

This is how i configure my stomp endpoints in the class that implemtents WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {  
    registry
        .addEndpoint("/websocket/endpoint")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker(...)
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(...);
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix(...);
  }

...
}
```

and here is my OAuth2 setup:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // configure oauth2 filter
    http
        // start chain for restricting access.
        .authorizeRequests()
        // for these paths
        .mvcMatchers("/websocket/endpoint")
        // require user to at least be authenticated (protect with oauth2)
        .authenticated()
        // for any other requests
        .anyRequest()
        // allow everything
        .permitAll();
  }

 ...
}
```

with all above up and running, the code below is able to connect to /websocket/endpoint without any additional setup for OAuth2:

```js
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/websocket/endpoint');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/publicChatRoom', function (helloMessage) {
            console.log(helloMessage.body);
            showChatMessage(JSON.parse(helloMessage.body).messageContent);
        });
    });
}
```

Am i missing any configurations or something?